# postgresql [42883] ERROR: function to_tsvector("unknown", "unknown") does not exist

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am new to postgresql and am attempting to use the full text search `to_tsvector` however I am running into an error.

SQL and error

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');

[42883] ERROR: function to_tsvector("unknown", "unknown") does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

SQL and error for different attempt

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english'::character, 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'::character);

[42883] ERROR: function to_tsvector(character, character) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

This is frustrating because this feels like the 'hello world' of getting to_tsvector working however I cannot even get this to return. I am using DataGrip 2020.2 with Postgres, but am not sure how to see which version of postgres I am using (i think it is a newer version). Is there a clear mistake in my code above?

Comment: Either this is not normal PostgreSQL, or it got corrupted, or you dropped some system objects, or you are using an ancient version. Please tell us more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to check, what types are used (I am using `psql` client`):

```
postgres=# \df to_tsvector
                             List of functions
┌────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────┐
│   Schema   │    Name     │ Result data type │ Argument data types │ Type │
╞════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ pg_catalog │ to_tsvector │ tsvector         │ json                │ func │
│ pg_catalog │ to_tsvector │ tsvector         │ jsonb               │ func │
│ pg_catalog │ to_tsvector │ tsvector         │ regconfig, json     │ func │
│ pg_catalog │ to_tsvector │ tsvector         │ regconfig, jsonb    │ func │
│ pg_catalog │ to_tsvector │ tsvector         │ regconfig, text     │ func │
│ pg_catalog │ to_tsvector │ tsvector         │ text                │ func │
└────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘
(6 rows)
```

There is not any variant for type `character`, `character`.

Your first query is working in my comp. Please, check, version of Postgres, that you use. Older (very old - years unsupported releases) Postgres has not this functionality

```
postgres=# SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the    lazy dog.');
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                      to_tsvector                      │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 'brown':3 'dog':9 'fox':4 'jump':5 'lazi':8 'quick':2 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

When you want to use explicit types, you can use `regconfig` and `text`:

```
postgres=# SELECT to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, 
                   'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'::text);
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                      to_tsvector                      │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 'brown':3 'dog':9 'fox':4 'jump':5 'lazi':8 'quick':2 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```